# Remove certain sizes from srcset in Wordpress images

Tags: php, wordpress, image, responsive-design, srcset

as we all know since Wordpress 4.4 there are responsive images sizes. My goal is to remove 2 sizes from generation and even from displaying in the srcset of the images. For some reason even after using the following code, the 2 sizes still displayed in the srcset! Any solutions maybe? :)

```
add_action( 'init', 'j0e_remove_large_image_sizes' );
function j0e_remove_large_image_sizes() {
  remove_image_size( '1536x1536' );             // 2 x Medium Large (1536 x 1536)
  remove_image_size( '2048x2048' );             // 2 x Large (2048 x 2048)
}

function remove_default_image_sizes( $sizes) {
unset( $sizes['1536×1536']);
unset( $sizes['2048×2048']);
return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'remove_default_image_sizes');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` will work, but it looks like you've set the wrong keys there. The `×` is the wrong character.

The following should work fine:

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', function( $new_sizes, $image_meta, $attachment_id ) {
    unset( $new_sizes['1536x1536'] );
    unset( $new_sizes['2048x2048'] );
    return $new_sizes;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: After adding this code into my child theme functions.php it still adds these sizes to the srcset of the images. :(

Comment: Are you sure the filter is being called? And please note this will unset these image sizes when you upload a new image. This will not remove image sizes for already uploaded images.

Answer (score 2):

hook into `wp_calculate_image_srcset` in wp-includes/media.php:1061-1180; read [detailed explanation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291895/how-to-exclude-an-image-size-from-the-wordpress-srcset)
`$sources` is an array that holds all available sizes for the `srcset` attribute. You can unset undesired sizes as shown below.

```
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', 'my_custom_image_srcset', 10, 5);

function my_custom_image_srcset($sources, $size_array, $image_src, $image_meta, $attachment_id) {
    $remove = ['1536', '2048'];
    $sources = array_diff_key($sources, array_flip($remove));
    //check result with print_r
    //print_r($sources);
    return $sources;
}
```